# WebAPI/OWIN hosting confusion

Tags: asp.net-web-api

There are so many things today? I'm looking to host web api in windows service but recently I come across this link http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

is this a new thing and should we use this OWIN, Please suggest?
Does this OWIN make thing more faster or what are the benefit to use OWIN?

Answer (score 0):

OWIN makes things a bit simpler and cleaner when self-hosting.

You might want to check out the [OWIN Web API 2 self host in windows service example](https://github.com/danesparza/OWIN-WebAPI-Service) on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Web API is based on owin, and owin is an abstraction. Instead of those old times when web api team was responsible for making web api availble on several hosts such as IIS, self host, etc, it just relays on owin. Owin has several implementations based on IIS, ASP.NET, ASP.NET Core, Self Host etc.
For example see the following sample of running asp.net web api odata on asp.net core using owin & kestrel: https://github.com/ymoradi/OwinAspNetCore

Answer (score -1):

After doing more searching OWIN and Kanata are just layers on top particularly WebAPI, they are rather an convenient composer from what I understand from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn451439.aspx

for my purpose, I use WebAPI ONLY, so I don't need all these extra things.